# Collect errors in Testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to find where or how can I collect the errors shown in iTunes Connect, in my app > Testflight > Testflight compilations. This is a screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible to collect these errors? Are they those feedback mails sent via Testflight iOS app?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Xcode. "Window" -> "Organizer" and select the tab "Crashes"

There you will see all crash-logs sorted by app and build-number. You should keep your app archives to receive the crashlogs.

---

You might not see a crashlog for every crash, but most of them. I don't know why, but sometimes it takes a while and some crashes simply don't appear.